# 555 delayed after threshold goes above control voltage

Tags: 555

I am messing around with some 555s I bought a while back (NE555N from STMicroelectronics) and I'm getting some unexpected behavior. I have a capacitor hooked up to both the trigger and threshold pins in order to give me a basic oscillator. The issue I'm having, however, is that once the voltage across the capacitor reaches the reference voltage and goes above it, it takes a fairly long time for the 555 to switch states, and much longer than it takes to trigger when the voltage drops below 1/2 of control.

[image: Normal control voltage]

[image: Reduced control voltage with resistors]

I've looked at a few things and honestly I'm not sure if I somehow accidentally fried the 555 or what. I tried two different 555s from the same package, I'm assuming it won't be any different if I grab a third one though. I'm currently running them from a 12V supply voltage, but had the same results with 5V.

EDIT:

I apologize for the crudity of this model... I don't know why it came out so blurry, should be legible though.

[image: Diagram]

EDIT: Fixed schematic to accurately show my hookup and also fixed blurriness.

Comment: Schematic ... ?

Comment: Please show your circuit.  Chances are pretty good that its incorrect

Comment: Schematic added... probably not the clearest but I drew it in like 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the the timing circuit miswired, and it would be nice if you had reference designators on your sketch.

Here's the right way, at (b):

[image]

I've taken the liberty of adding reference designations to your drawing, and with the values you've given for R1, R2, and C2, the output frequency should be, according to:

\$f=1.46/(R1+2R2)C2\$,

about 20.7 MHz.

Since the ceiling for a bipolar 555 is around 1 MHz, clearly something's wrong.

[image]

According to your screen shots, the frequency is 273.2 kHz which, with R1 and R2 equal to 500 ohms each, would make C2 equal to about 3.6 **nano** farads, so I suspect that, considering the frequency error possible because of the tolerance buildup between R1, R2, C2, and the 555 itself, you read the value of C2's decimal multiplier incorrectly.

As an aside, the proper use of the voltage control function of pin 5 is given starting on page 9 of the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf).

Comment: Dur... I made a mistake in the schematic. No, my capacitor is hooked to ground, the top two are connected. The circuit in (b) is as I have it wired. My apologies.

Comment: For fun, I hooked it up the way I had drawn it originally. Funnily enough, it kinda still works. The rise and fall on the trigger/threshold part are practically vertical lines now.

Comment: I suspect your circuit is operating properly.In the astable mode, wired per the schematic I posted, the 555 trigger points are at 1/3 and 2/3 Vcc.

Comment: Yeah, and that blue line is the vref(connected to pin 5) which should be the 2/3 VCC that we're talking about, correct? I can get the oscillation up to about 400 kHz by connecting the control pin to ground with a 500ohm resistor.. Maybe the 500+kHz in the datasheet was overly optimistic? I've heard of people getting 555s up to a couple MHz before though, but it probably depends on the type. Thought I'd try it for myself....

Comment: Got it up to 700khz by connecting the ctrl back to ground with the resistor and removing my capacitor connected to the trig and thr pins and using breadboard capacitance instead. Close enough for today.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to close things up here... It seems bipolar based 555s are just slow(Which I kind of knew before, but I wasn't thinking about it). Hitting 500kHz like in the datasheet requires a bit of playing around. However, I also had a pack of CMOS 555s laying around, so I threw one of those into this circuit and got a 4.5MHz clock rate no problem.

So to answer my own question: no, there's nothing wrong with my circuit, and not much I can do with it aside from trying to trick it like I was by dropping the control voltage way down. CMOS is the way to get much more speed out of it.

Oh, and I did get the bipolar one up to about 1.2MHz with a can of freeze spray...